# Is there a way to not request location permission after LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE permission has been granted on the system settings, on an Expo Project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am doing a react native project on expo. When a user have a "never" permission on the phone, when pressing share location button, the app asks if the user wants to change location manually and if "yes" the app redirects to system settings.

However when the user turns back and I try to access location through method getCurrentPositionAsync (expo-location library) and I still see the "LOCATION_FOREGROUND permission is required to do this operation" error, even though the LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE permission has been granted on the system settings, because my app has not requested the permission through the expo-location API.

Is there a way to achieve this on an expo project, without having to ask twice? (testing on iphone)

Comment: what is result of this in your app `const [status, requestPermission] = Location.useForegroundPermissions();` when your return to the app aster setttigs were changed your app restarts and you can check permissons

Comment: @KirillNovikov I am using a class base component. When I return to the app, the method getForegroundPermissionsAsync() return me this object `Object {
  "canAskAgain": true,
  "expires": "never",
  "granted": false,
  "status": "denied",
}` So I can now request for permissions but I still have to ask form them.

Comment: from your response you can't because "granted": false,   "status": "denied"

Comment: @KirillNovikov Yes the problem is precisely that. At this point, the location should be already accessible, not having to request for permission again.